# Call functions in View Model?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view model

```
 public class PersonsViewmodel
    {
     public string FirstName { get; set; }// from DB
     public string LastName { get; set; }// from DB
     public string FullName { get; set; } // this should be a custom value
 }
```

> The linq query

```
  var per = from p in db.Persons  where p.Active==0          
                     select new PersonsViewmodel
                     { FirstName =p.FirstName ,LastName =p.LastName ,
FullName =Reg(p.FirstName)
};

public static string Reg(string str)
                 {
                    return str = Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "-", RegexOptions.Compiled);
                 }
```

This throws a error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   reg(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into
>   a store expression.

Is there a better way to call this Reg function in the model itself instead of calling in the linq query or should i call the function after the linq query?

Right now I am doing this operation in the View like

```
@{
var FullName = Regex.Replace(model.FirstName, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "-");
}
```

and using the variable FullName to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that a job for the view model?

```
public class PersonsViewmodel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }// from DB
    public string LastName { get; set; }// from DB
    public string FullName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return Regex.Replace(FirstName, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "-", RegexOptions.Compiled); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it afterwards.  When you are writing LINQ queries you have to remember that if it can't be translated to T-SQL it probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Malcolm is right, LINQ2SQL tries to translate the whole expression to T-SQL, which is not always possible.

You can try to do it afterwards:

```
var pre = ...LINQ2SQL query...;
var pre2 = pre.ToList().Select(p =>{ p.FirstName, p.LastName, FullName =Reg(p.FirstName)});
```